# Save a state of checkbox to specific line of file C #

Tags: c#, checkbox, save

I've searched multiple solutions and coudnt find the one specificly adressing my issue:

What i want to accomplish is to save a state of checkbox to specific line of file.
I have used identical code for saving patch of file from openFileDialog.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("patcher.conf");
lines[0] = openFileDialog1.FileName;
File.WriteAllLines("patcher.conf", lines);
}
```

code above saves file patch in 1st (0 indexed) line of text file, and it works!
But for some reason when i try to do exacly the same thing in :

```
private void checkexe_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("patcher.conf");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("patcher.conf");
            lines[1] = checkexe.Checked.ToString();
            File.WriteAllLines("patcher.conf", lines);
        }
        file.Close();
    }
```

and save information about state of checkbox in 2nd (1 indexed line of file) the error says :
process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for writing the file is flawed. You are opening the file and reading all lines, but for every line, you are then reading all lines again and saving the file in the same loop. This would be the cause of your `process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` error.

```
private void checkexe_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("patcher.conf");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("patcher.conf");
        lines[1] = checkexe.Checked.ToString();
        File.WriteAllLines("patcher.conf", lines);
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

Instead, try below: (untested, but should get you in the right direction)

```
private void checkexe_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("patcher.conf");
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            lines[i] = checkexe.Checked.ToString();
    }
    File.WriteAllLines("patcher.conf", lines);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Now i see it more clearly how it shoud be done - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the file stream, you have use readwrite

System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(txtFilePath.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read,System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);

System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);

Comment: I'm a little confused - shoud i use it with my code somehow? Where do i put it ?
How do i save to specific line of text file with this?

Comment: Is this all the code you have? The error is that it can't write to the file because another file already has it locked for writing. Are you using a StreamReader?

Comment: just updated the code - here you see the stream reader. (all previous stream readers are file.Close() -ed)
Edit:
OK i think the answer just striked me - is it possible that event : checkexe_CheckedChanged fires during form load ?